# How to prevent generation of css files for sass with CRA without ejecting?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

Trying to use SASS or LESS without ejecting.

Successfully configured following the link below:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc

But its generating `.scss` to `.css` in run-time and need to rely on `.css` while importing from the components which is a bit confusing during development.

Is there way to just rely on `.scss` only like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import style from "./App.scss"; --> Sass import as module

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.welcome}>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**And in App.scss File:**

```
.welcome { color: red; }
```

But this is not working, can someone brief on how to get rid of this situation. It would have been awesome if `create-react-app` would have been provided --sass setup while configuring the new project to true or false. But unfortunately, its all customized for now.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to modify webpack config for that kind of operation, (mean eject)

Comment: any other hack without ejection plz @FabienGreard?

Comment: I'm sorry the other options i see would be too heavy (implementing a task manager, gulp/grunt) better to eject :/

Comment: But [this link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4195) tells something else, also in the [webpack.dev.config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L309) there is comments regarding Opt-in support for SASS, are we missing something?

Comment: @Javed not in the official release yet, it's merged into `@next`?

Comment: @anderssonola thanks got it!

Comment: One option is to use the next version of CRA to get the sass support `upgrade react-scripts@next`

Comment: What is the right command to upgrade cra?

Comment: @anderssonola - worked with `yarn upgrade react-scripts@next`. So now the react-scripts got changed to: `react-scripts": "^2.0.0-next.a671462c"`

Comment: I get this error: `./src/test.scss)
Module build failed: Error: `sass-loader` requires `node-sass` >=4. Please install a compatible version.` after upgrading :(

Comment: I finally managed to solve with adding node-sass as an external dev dependency to get rid of the above error: `"node-sass" : "^4.9.3"`. Thanks all

Comment: @anderssonola - all these days it was working fine with this next un-official upgrade. it has stopped now. `"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.0.0-next.a671462c",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
  }` is my dependency. Can you please help if i am missing something?